# Сделать часть круга svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg

В общем мне желательно сделать часть круга, размер которой можно будет редактировать в % и при натяжке не было проблем. Т.е. зависимость заполнения круга от %.  [image: Зависимость процента заполнения круга]
Я лишь смог сделать полукруг:

```
<svg version="1.1"
 baseProfile="full"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="400" height="400">
<g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)">      
<circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#673E93" stroke-width="5"   stroke-dasharray ="314 " stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" /> 
</g> 
</svg>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
let value = Math.random()*100;
text.innerHTML = value.toFixed(0) + '%'
fon.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', 2*Math.PI*value + ' 1000' )
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
  <g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)">      
    <circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" 
      stroke="#673E93" stroke-width="5" fill="none" /> 
  </g>
  <text x="150" y="150" fill=#673E93 id=text font-size=50 
    text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=central ></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Код JS классный!

Comment: Спасибо, я немного изменил под себя код, благодарю за решение)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Может посмотришь [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1058321/28748) и примешь участие в решении?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT заплюсовал, буду у компа - гляну

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Благодарю. Решение любое, интересует более короткий и оптимальный код, как ты умеешь